# Cmake >= 3.17 - pre build script execution - Soltution?

Tags: cmake

In cmake there is custom commands, which can run PRE_BUILD or PRE_LINK or POST_BUILD.
However, on most platforms, except Visual Studio apparently, PRE_BUILD and PRE_LINK are idendical.

There are plenty of posts here about this issue, all stating this fact but noone giving a possible solution to "acutally PRE BUILD do something".

I for example need to run a bash script which will create some headers (c and c++ headers) automatically, and the source depends on them being A.) available and B.) defining certain things.

Is there an alternative to the custom command in cmake? How is it possible to execute something before the cmake process takes over and starts compiling things?

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRE_BUILD <---------------------------------------- THIS IS PRE_LINK unfortunatelly!
    COMMAND ../my_bash_script.sh
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    VERBATIM
)
```

Comment: "I for example need to run a bash script which will create some headers" - Do you want to run this script **unconditionally** whenever your executable is needed to be rebuilt (e.g. because some source file is changed)? This is what `PRE_BUILD` event means. Otherwise, If you want to run the script only when resulted headers are not existed yet, then use the "normal" form of `add_custom_command` which accepts OUTPUT option as the first parameter.

Comment: Ok thank you but so far i am not there yet. First i need to make it execute BEFORE cmake and make/ninja/.. execute, not adter

Comment: When program in CMake it is better to does NOT think like "I want to execute `A` *before* `B`" but think like "Executing `B` **requires** a file `foo.h`, and this file is produced by `A`". In other words, think in term of **dependencies**, not in term of *ordering*. E.g. if your script produces the file `foo.h` which is required for build the executable, then create `add_custom_command` which OUTPUT is `foo.h` and which COMMAND runs your script. Then add `foo.h` into `add_executable` call. Before compiling the executable CMake will sure that `foo.h` exists. If not, your script will be run.

Comment: Aha ok good explaination! Thank you ill try this with dependencies.